# Tweepy API calls not working

Tags: python, tweepy

I started using Tweepy for a project. So far I've got the following to work.

- authentication
- getting streams
- filtering streams
- update the status

However, I can't get some of the API calls to work, most of them return `API object has no attribute ______`

for eg:

```
api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.trends()
```

return `API object has no attribute trends`

Does anyone know if the documentation is outdated or am I doing something wrong ?

[Documentation I'm using](http://pythonhosted.org/tweepy/html/api.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you refer to, is for version 1.4 but the current released versions are 1.13 and 2.0; I'd expect the latter especially to no longer match that documentation.

However, the [Tweepy API](http://tweepy.github.io/) directly reflects the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs).

For trends for example, there are several *separate* methods:

- [`/trends/place`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/place)
- [`/trends/available`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/available)
- [`/trends/closest`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/trends/closest)

As such, `api.trends_available()` should work just fine; replace path separators by underscores.

Answer (score 1):

For woeid codes I guess api.trends_place(woeid) works fine. For example if you want to get the trending topics in world just replace woeid = 1 or for India = 23424848. Similarly you could do it for other geographic locations too. Similarly api.trends_closest(woeid) and api.trends_available() works for the tweepy library.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might indeed be incorrect documentation. I would suggest to have a look at:

https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py
You can search for trend and will be able to see what attributes the api has.

```
    api.trends_available
```

should do the trick.

Tweepy mirrors the twitter api, so checking there will give you an insight as to what is available to you.